# Song.fromURI() throwing Exception?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xna, xna-4.0

I've been trying to include the Song.FromURI() method in my current app, yet a "CrossThreadMessagingException" always occurs.

I have started a new project and have literally copy and pasted the code from the MSDN example (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff634558.aspx) and yet the exception still occurs. It appears to be silent (no termination) but prevents access to any members.

Thanks.

```
Uri uriStreaming = new Uri("http://www.archive.org/download/gd1977-05-08.shure57.stevenson.29303.flac16/gd1977-05-08d02t06_vbr.mp3");
Song song = Song.FromUri("StreamingUri", uriStreaming);


'song.Album' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.CrossThreadMessagingException'
'song.Artist' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.CrossThreadMessagingException'
'song.Genre' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.CrossThreadMessagingException'
'song.PlayCount' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.CrossThreadMessagingException'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shawn Hargreaves from the XNA Team posted this on MSDN a while back that I believe is relative  to what you have here:

> Many of the media player properties cannot be evaluated when your
>   program is paused in the debugger. It's not possible to run complex
>   property getters that involve communicating with the media player
>   thread, because that thread is suspended while your program is broken
>   in the debugger, so is unable to run the code that would normally
>   report the value of the property.
>
> This is just a debugger artifact, and should not cause any problems if
>   you run your program normally, or step through it in the debugger. It
>   only affects the debugger property display, not the actual execution
>   of your code.